# Onkeyup event in Javascript is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, keyboard-events

I'm using the event like onkeyup and onkeydown function. In that I tried to disable the <kbd>printscr</kbd>  alone using Javascript. I Googled in that <kbd>alt</kbd> key ASCII is 18 and <kbd>Printscr</kbd> is 44.

Here is the Code that I tried to disable:

```
document.onkeyup = function(e)
            {
                if (e.which === 44)
                {
                    alert('alt key pressed');
                    return false;
                }

            };
var isAlt = false;
document.onkeydown = function(e)
            {
                if (e.which === 18) {
                    isAlt === true;
                    if (((e.which === 44)) && isAlt === true)
                    {
                        alert('tested printscreen');
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            };
```

In that keyup alert is working, but return false is not firing. Also for the <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>printscr</kbd> is not getting the alert also. What shall I do? Is anything where I made a mistake?

Comment: I think the "false" in document's onkeyup is not usefull (document is really at the end of the event's chain). Furthermore, the event will be casted only if you have a focused element in the page (any input tag for exemple, a canvas, ...), if not nothing will be casted and thus no event will reach the "document" element.

Comment: Thanks for your Response then how can i make that printscreen to make return false;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at browser specific documentation for stopping events:

```
e.stopPropagation()
```

Also, in key up, the text box may have been populated with multiple characters from the key repeat.  In key down, you need to store the value.  In key up, restore that value if you get the 44 key.  And, you need to place the key handlers on window, not document.

```
(function() {

var savedValue;

window.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.altKey && e.which === 44) {
        alert('alt key pressed');

        if (undefined !== savedValue) {
            e.target.value = savedValue;
            savedValue = undefined;
        }
        return;
    }
};

window.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (undefined === savedValue) {
        savedValue = e.target.value;
    }

    if (e.altKey && e.which === 44) {
        alert("tested printscr");
    }
};

})();
```

Comment: Thanks Craig, I tried your Code still i didn't get any alert can you provide me the jsfiddle by this i could learn what i did mistake

Comment: Are you pressing the ALT key when pressing print screen?  Also, might be worth checking that you get that key at all by removing the altKey checks.  If you still don't see anything, I'd guess that the browser is not propagating printscr keypresses to the DOM.